# I want to check if I already have an object(subclass) in a map of different subclasses

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, virtualization

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

#include <map>

using namespace std;

class Carte:public IO{
    private:
        int nrPag;
        string autor;
        string nume;
    
    public:
       
        friend bool operator==(const Carte &obj1, const Carte &obj2){
            if(obj1.nrPag!=obj2.nrPag||obj1.autor!=obj2.autor||obj1.nume!=obj2.nume)
                return 0;
            return 1;
        }
        virtual int Compare(const Carte &obj1){
            if(*this==obj1)
                return 1;
            return 0;
        }


       
};


class CarteScience:virtual public Carte{
    protected:
        int an;
    public:
        
        friend bool operator==(const CarteScience &obj1, const CarteScience &obj2){
            if((Carte)obj1==(Carte)obj2)
                if(obj1.an==obj2.an)
                    return 1;
            return 0;
        }
        virtual int Compare(const CarteScience &obj1){
            if(*this==obj1)
                return 1;
            return 0;
        }

};

class CarteFiction:virtual public Carte{
    protected:
        string univers;
        float numarCreaturiMagice;
    public:
        
        friend bool operator==(const CarteFiction &obj1, const CarteFiction &obj2){
            if((Carte)obj1==(Carte)obj2)
                if(obj1.univers==obj2.univers&&obj1.numarCreaturiMagice==obj2.numarCreaturiMagice)
                    return 1;
            return 0;
        }
        virtual int Compare(const CarteFiction &obj1){
            if(*this==obj1)
                return 1;
            return 0;
        }


};

class CarteScienceFiction : public CarteFiction,public CarteScience{
    private :
        double procentReal;
    public:

        friend bool operator==(const CarteScienceFiction &obj1, const CarteScienceFiction &obj2){
            if((Carte)obj1==(Carte)obj2)
                if(obj1.univers==obj2.univers&&obj1.numarCreaturiMagice==obj2.numarCreaturiMagice&&obj1.an==obj2.an)
                    return 1;
            return 0;
        }
        int Compare(const CarteScienceFiction &obj1){
            if(*this==obj1)
                return 1;
            return 0;
        }


};
class Biblioteca{
    private:
        map<Carte*,int> CartiStoc;
        map<Carte*, int> CartiImprumutate;

    public:
        Biblioteca(){
            this->CartiStoc= {};
            this->CartiImprumutate = {};
        }
        void addStoc();
};
void Biblioteca::addStoc(){
    int k;
    cout << "Tasta 1 pentru carte science\nTasta 2 pentru carte fiction\nTasta 3 pentru carte science fiction";
    cin >> k;

    switch(k){
    case 1:{
        CarteScience* aux = new CarteScience();
        cin >> *aux;
        for (auto const& x: CartiStoc)
            {
                if((*aux).Compare(*x.first))
                    cout<<"2";
            }
        this->CartiStoc[aux] = 1;
        break;
    }
}
}
```

I made the virtual functions expecting to compare based on the type of subclass i have, but it just checks with the parent "Carte" type. I also checked to see if the overloading of == operator is done correctly and that s not the problem. please help
I also cut out any code that isn t related to the problem.

Comment: Add `override` to your "overrides" and you will see that they don't override anything.

Comment: Side note: use `bool`, `true`, and `false` for truth values, not `int`, `1`, and `0`.

Comment: The equality operator overload and the `Compare` function, I would do it the other way around. One generic `operator==` function which takes references to the base-class, Then it call the virtual `Compare` function for the actual comparison. Would simplify a lot of your code. Of course, to make it work and the `Compare` function being overridden properly, you need to do down-casting in it to the correct types (`auto& other = static_cast<TheActualClass&>(other_argument)`)

Comment: Realistically you should just compare the ISBN. Having different C++ classes for different book categories is impractical for a variety of reasons.

Answer (score 0):

It's because, compile-time, the argument to your `Compare` function is of type `Carte`. And there's only one function that accepts a `Carte`. The other accept a type of any of the sub classes, so they're not called.

Instead change it to something like:

```cpp
class CarteScience:virtual public Carte{
    protected:
        int an;
    public:
        
        friend bool operator==(const CarteScience &obj1, const CarteScience &obj2){
            if((Carte)obj1==(Carte)obj2)
                if(obj1.an==obj2.an)
                    return 1;
            return 0;
        }
        virtual int Compare(const Carte &obj1){ // change type to Carte
            if(dynamic_cast<CarteScience*>(&obj1) != null && *this==obj1)
                return 1;
            return 0;
        }

};

void Biblioteca::addStoc(){
    int k;
    cout << "Tasta 1 pentru carte science\nTasta 2 pentru carte fiction\nTasta 3 pentru carte science fiction";
    cin >> k;

    switch(k){
    case 1:{
        CarteScience* aux = new CarteScience();
        cin >> *aux;
        for (auto const& x: CartiStoc)
            {
                if (*x.first->Compare(*aux)) // Swap arguments so that dynamic binding calls the correct Compare function
                    cout<<"2";
            }
        this->CartiStoc[aux] = 1;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: i can t dynamic cast onto the const Carte cause it s a const and also i tried your solution and it s just compares the base class Carte .

Comment: This is all fine and dandy until you start having deep hierarchies. Say you have a library of geometric shapes and you compare them this way, and everything works perfectly. Triangles are compared to Triangles and Circles to Circles. Now you add colour, implement the comparison function of new ColouredTriangle and ColouredCircle class and everything else, and your library falls apart, because now a green triangle is never equal to a red triangle, even in geometry code that doesn't know or care about colour.

Comment: @Theo then cast to const Carte* instead of non-const Carte* and change your Compare function to be const.

Comment: i changed the if to this "if(dynamic_cast<const CarteScience*>(&obj1) != NULL && *this==*dynamic_cast<const CarteScience*>(&obj1))" and it works now ty

Comment: @Theo "it works now" are you sure? Try creating two books, one Science, once ScienceFiction, with all the *common* attributes the same. Now compare `book1 == book2` and `book2 == book1`. Do you get the same result with two comparisons?